# use variable name in code processing php like $number01 use it value, not name

Tags: php

so better will be example (so hard to give a title to this problem)

imagine I have variables in php like

```
 $number1 = 10;
 $number2 = 30;
 $number3 = 23;
```

.. and so on..

and I just want to make an arithmetic average but not like

($number1 + $number2 +$number3)/3  because it is so much typing (having more than only 3 numbers)

but use something like

```
 $temp=0;
 for ($i=1;$i<50;$i++){


 $temp=$temp+$number."$i";   <- this is what I don't know how to define..

 }
```

and similar, how to echo all values for numbers like

```
for ($i=1;$i<50;$i++){

 echo $number.$i;   <- but this is not working..

 }
```

I hope I have described it good, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with variable variables but it's ugly:

```
 $temp=0;
 for ($i=1;$i<50;$i++){
     $temp=$temp+(${$number.$i});
 }
```

There is a limitation with the variable variables which is you don't know how high the number goes. You would also need to check if the variable is set first. A better solution is to store each of the variables in an array, which you can easily iterate over:

```
 $arr = array();
 $arr[] = 10;
 $arr[] = 30;
 $arr[] = 23;

$temp = 0;
foreach($arr as $val)
{
    $temp += $val;
}
```

Comment: you can even use array_sum on an array which is very handy for this exact situation

Comment: @Dale, yeah the shortcut functions are great and will be faster than coding it yourself but here I want to demonstrate the basic use of arrays and iterating over the array. I'm kind of saying learn to walk before you can run so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

```
$number = array(10,20,30);
echo array_sum($number);
```

the other solution doing the same with for loop

```
$number = array(10,20,30);
$count = count($number);
$sum = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $count ; ++$i) $sum += $number[$i];
```

or foreach

```
$number = array(10,20,30);
$count = count($number);
$sum = 0;
foreach($number as $n) $sum += $n;
```

there are a lot of methods to add items to array for example

```
$number  = array(10,20,30);

$number  = array();
$number[] = 10; $number[] = 20; $number[] = 30;
$number[0]= 10; $number[1] = 20; $number[2] = 30;

$number = array();
array_push($number, 10, 20, 30);
```

But the most simple and working solution is to use arrays and [array_sum()](https://www.php.net/array_sum) function.

**Array sum** - Calculate the sum of values in an array

Answer (score 0):

use an array

```
$number[0] = 10;
$number[1] = 20;
$number[2] = 23;

for ($i=1;$i<count($number);$i++) {
  echo $number[$i]; //now this works.
}
```

Comment: thank you all! I will use arrays for that! Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to put all these values into an array instead of different variables. This makes adding later easier and allows you to loop like:

```
foreach($myArray as $number){
    echo $number;
}
```

If you still want/need to use variables you can use variable variables:

```
$temp=0;
 for ($i=1;$i<50;$i++){

$numberName = "number".$i;
 $temp=$temp + $$numberName;//Note the $$ syntax.

 }
```

`$$foo` will be the value of the variable with the name stored in `$foo`.

A final note. Be careful with variable variables, as they can lead to messy or unreadable code.